# Joomla Calendar field does not work when given format as D dS M Y

Tags: joomla-4, fields, calendar, format

In my XML form, I have given a calendar field in the `format='D dS M Y'` which is as follows

```
<field name="certificationdate"
class="inputbox" 
format="D dS M Y" 
timeformat="12" 
filter="server_utc" 
translateformat="false" 
showtime="false" 
singleheader="false" 
todaybutton="false" 
weeknumbers="false" 
filltable="false" 
type="calendar" 
label="COM_ANAND_FORM_LBL_ANAND_DET_CERTIFICATIONDATE"
description="COM_ANAND_FORM_DESC_ANAND_DET_CERTIFICATIONDATE"
hint="COM_ANAND_FORM_LBL_ANAND_DET_CERTIFICATIONDATE"/>
```

Can someone tell what can be the reason for not working the calendar field with the given format? It only works for the default date format, even tried to update created calendar field of the article.xml file there also it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Joomla seems to work with the date/time format defined in [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) rather than [Datetime format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

But even with that there is something odd about the %g and %G parameters. It's as if there's some javascript that is changing the 2 or 4 digit representation of the year back to %g or %G ... Use %y or %Y for the year instead.